# Can the Precision, Recall and F1 be the same value?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, precision, precision-recall

I am working on an ML classification problem and I'm computing the Precision, Recall and F1 using the `sklearn` library's following import and respective code as shown below.

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support

print(precision_recall_fscore_support(y_test, prob_pos, average='weighted'))
```

**Results**

```
0.8806451612903226, 0.8806451612903226, 0.8806451612903226
```

Is there a possibility to get the same value for all 3, the precision, recall and F1 for an ML classification problem?

Comment: Precision and recall could be if the FP and FN are 0.5/0.5 F1 is unlikely...

Comment: @Rob Thanks for getting back. So does this imply that there might be an error in the classifier prediction?

Comment: You can check that if you print the number of `false_positives` and `false_negatives`. If those 2 numbers are the same, then you're ok. But as @Rob said, it's unlikely.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Let's assume binary classification with

[image: Pr = TP / (TP + FP); Re = (TP + FN); F1 = 2TP / (2TP + FP + FN)]

The trivial solution to `Pr = Re = F1` is `TP = 0`. So we know precision, recall and F1 can have the same value in general. Now, this does not apply to your specific result. If we solve the system of equations, we find another solution: `FP = FN`. So, if the number of false positives is the same as the number of false negatives, all three metrics have identical values.

For multiclass classification problems we have

[image: F1 = 2 * (Pr * Re) / (Pr + Re)]

If `Pr = Re`, again all three metrics are identical.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be because of the option `average='weighted'`.

Refer: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html

> 'weighted':
> Calculate metrics for each label, and find their average weighted by support (the number of true instances for each label). This alters ‘macro’ to account for label imbalance; it can result in an F-score that is not between precision and recall.